# ionic apk ,button or href active on double click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, apk

That am facing the problem on  the ionic app ,it is working fine on the ripple emulator , but when i create an apk then i am facing that problem in the device , on double click only the button or the href link is working ,  so please help me for solve this issue, thanking  you

Comment: can u show some code

Comment: @SaEChowdary, <a href="" ng-click="findlocation(gdata.callID)"><img src="images/icons/turquoise/map.png" style="height:30px;width:30px" /></a> , this is how i used the href

Comment: try with removing href=""

Comment: @SaEChowdary , same its dosen't change

Answer (score 0):

You donot need an anchor tag for the click function. Just put the ng-click on your img tag, it will work. like so :

```
<img ng-click="findlocation(gdata.callID)" src="images/icons/turquoise/map.png" style="height:30px;width:30px" />
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but its dosen't  differ by adding or removing  the anchor tag ,as if its working fine in the emulator but when generating an apk this issue is raising

Comment: which device did you test it on?

Comment: on the android device of version 6.0